# How to safely connect to a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

right now I just have a file with my database name, user, password and host. If someone were to just double click that file they'd have lots of private information. How do I go about changing it so they can't just see my db information. FYI PHP + MySql.
EDIT:
How is it hard to understand? I have a db file called db.php with all the info nessesary to connect to a db. If someone were to go on my computer and double click the file (db.php) they would see my info. In real life situation a hacker could obtain this file. How can I fix this so a hacker could not see the db info but I could still conect to the database?

It's a legitimate question.

Comment: Well what type of file is it? How is it stored? Where is it stored...?

Comment: How is i hard to understand? I have a db file called db.php with all the info nessesary to connect to a db. If someone were to go on my computer and double click the file (db.php) they would see my info. In real life situation a hacker could obtain this file. How can I fix this? @Darren

Comment: Urm, put it outside the document root? If a hacker can access your files that should be the least of your worries!

Comment: @3legit4quit No mate, you're acting like the retard here. Read this carefully - If somebody wants your database credentials, they **will** find a way. If a hacker can access your server and view your files (**which is the LEAST of your worries**) then they can practically do what they want, they can root your server and access **everything**. (*I'm not going to go into too much detail here*) You can either encrypt your file with something like IonCube, but still there is a possibility of it being decrypted. Now for your local file issue, take more precaution as in cillosis's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server will be configured to process certain file types. For example, when you load a PHP page, it doesn't (or shouldn't) output the PHP to the screen -- instead it processes it.

You have a couple good options for protecting this information.

1) Store the details in a PHP file as variables (you are most likely doing this). A lot of times, these will be in an array:

```
$dbParams = array(
   'database' => 'my_db',
   'host'     => 'localhost',
   'username' => 'my_web_user',
   'password' => 'abc123',
);
```

As long as you never output the `$dbParams` variable, you are fine.

2) Another option is to use something like you see above, but instead of literal values, you pull in [environment variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php).

```
$dbParams = array(
   'database' => $_ENV['myapp_db_name'],
   'host'     => $_ENV['myapp_db_host'],
   'username' => $_ENV['myapp_db_username'],
   'password' => $_ENV['myapp_db_password'],
);
```

Then in your server configuration, you would set those environment variables to whatever you need. In this way, if for some reason PHP stopped working and it started outputting your web files as plain text, they would never see your sensitive information. You will also notice I *namespaced* the environment variable. This is a good idea as they are global and if you just used something like `host` you would most likely have a collision.

[EDIT]

Reading your updated comments, it sounds like you are worried about files on your local computer -- not a webserver. You should take the precautions necessary to secure your local computer from remote access as you would normally (i.e. firewall, virus scanning to hopefully prevent trojans, etc.). In reality, unless you are Facebook or Google, people probably wouldn't really care what your local database password is.